# Check commit details of a SSH key

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

In a `git commit` I want to check which machine I used to make that commit, for which I would like to check the SSH key for same in a commit.

Any help for same?

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not clear, but if i'm understanding you you want to know from which machine your commit was done.

The simple answer:

> **You can't**.

#### The long answer:

Users can have the same key (ssh) used on several machines.

*How*?

Simply copy your `.ssh` folders between your different machines and you will use the **same** private key on all all of them.

In git you cant get the information who is the user (you can use `-c` to pass any data you want to fake), from where did he commit and so on.

What you need to do it to filter it in your server/router whatever, which means - you cant get this info with git and it has to be on the network level.

Comment: You got the question correct, but suppose I know I have different ssh keys on different machines then is there way in git to check same? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> suppose I know I have different ssh keys on different machines then is there way in git to check same?

git has simply no (or very little) notion of ssh, or https.
Those protocols are used for accessing (ion clone fetch or pull) a listener on the server (hosting your git repos), which in turn calls git.
They can be used for authentication (which is completely ignored by git)

git knows only about ssh when used as a client fetching repos ([`connect.c`#L733-L783](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d722536dd86b5fbd0c0434bfcea5588132ee6ad/connect.c#L733-L783) implements [`git_connect()`](https://github.com/git/git/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=git_connect))

But your question is about the server, inspecting commits, and determining their origin: the information is simply not there.

Only an intermediate authorization layer like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#overview) could at least [records the IP of the `git push` operation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#lff), which is a bit more precise than an ssh key anyway.
That even allows to [restrict access to a repo by source IP address](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#example-2-restricting-by-source-ip-address).

But git alone does not know how to do that.

Comment: That is little weird from git servers side then, looks like a basic log tracking..But thanks for details

Comment: @KaushikRay there is "git server" at all: git is a local file manager (which can then be contacted through listeners like ssh or https). And even if git logged, it would log IP addresses, not ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use `git config --global user.name` on login to the server to set something up

Add a command like this to the .bashrc or similar

```
git config --global --add user.name "$USER on "`hostname`
```

Then "git log" output is like this

```
commit f30396c75765f14e377c221bde1fe74a912afa92
Author: jamie on myhost.woowoo.com <james.andrews@iop.org>
Date:   Wed Jan 6 12:55:59 2016 +0000

    hopefully working
```